# Best version of DOSBox for macOS (Homebrew version seems abandoned)

Tags: homebrew

I've been using DOSBox through Homebrew for years, and now it won't update because of a SHA256 mismatch error. I tried all possible updates and cleanups in Homebrew to no avail. According to Homebrew, this means the brew is abandoned. DOSBox was last updated in 2010.

What is the best version of DOSBox for macOS, preferably available through Homebrew?

Comment: I've been using Boxer http://boxerapp.com but it hasn't been updated for 2 years...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DOSBox-X](https://github.com/joncampbell123/dosbox-x/releases) is your best bet, it's the only one that is currently being updated. I'm not sure what makes you think it's Japanese, it's managed by [a guy in Seattle, WA, USA](https://github.com/joncampbell123).

I have no issues with it and keyboard typing. I am using British-PC layout and a wired Apple aluminium keyboard with numeric pad.

[image]

Comment: Best suggestion so far. I was able to work around the keyboard problems on a non-US keyboard by manually creating a `dosbox.conf` file containing the lines `[sdl]` and `usescancodes=true`. Reported this as issues.

Comment: Started using it. There are some issues, but the community is active and responding brilliantly to issues, so I'm very positive so far!

Comment: Great news! Really happy for you.